# Publish c# symbols to NuGet package using NuGet Package Manager

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package-explorer

I know there is a way to do this using CLI. Is there a way to publish symbols for debugging packages in development using the NuGet Package Manager?

Asked another way, how to debug a package when the package is not able to run in a stand alone manor?

Answer (score 0):

Boy...do I feel stupid! After sleeping on it it hit me.

1. Create a new Solution [MySolution].
2. Add the project [MyNuGetSolution] that is targeted toward making a NuGet package.
3. Add a reference to the [MyNuGetSolution] from inside [MySolution].

Develop to your hearts content! When you get the [MyNuGetSolution] to the point that you are happy then work on packaging it and using it in other solutions.

Sometimes the obvious eludes me!